# How to test Azure ARM API using mockito?

Tags: java, azure, junit, mocking, mockito

I am working on azure ARM methods like provision VM and list all VM's using java sdk. I want to test my method using mockito. How can I do that without making original call to azure.

```
public class ListAllVM{
    public static Azure azure = null;
    public void listAllVM() {
    azure = getAuthentication();
    try {
        int i = 0;
        for (VirtualMachine VM : azure.virtualMachines().list()) {
            System.out.println(++i +
                    " \n VM ID:-" +  VM.id() +
                    " \n VM Name:-" +  VM.name() +
                    "\n");
        }
    } catch (CloudException | IOException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        log.info("Listing vm failed");      }
  }
}
```

I am facing problem while getting mock list of vm. How to mock external API class.

Comment: I just noticed that you never came back on my answer. Please let me know if I can do something to make it upvote/accept worthy in your eyes.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is: you wrote **hard** to test code - by using **static** and **new**. A quick suggestion how to do things differently:

```
public class AzureUtils {
  private final Azure azure;

  public AzureUtils()  { this (  getAuthentication(); }
  AzureUtils(Azure azure) { this.azure = azure };

  public List<VM> getVms() {
     return azure.virtualMachines.list();
  }
```

In my version, you can use **dependency injection** to **insert** a **mocked** version of Azure.class. Now you can use any kind of *mocking framework* (like EasyMock or Mokito) to provide an Azure object that (again) returns mocked objects.

For the record: I am not sure where your code is getting **getAuthentication()** from; so unless this is a static import; something is wrong with your code in the first place.

In other words: you want to learn how to write **testable** code; for example by watching these [videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLD0011D00849E1B79).

On the other hand one comment says that the Azure class is final; and its constructor is private. Which is well, perfectly fair: when you design an API using *final* is a powerful tool to express intent.

Coming from there, you are actually pretty limited to:

- as written above: you create an abstraction like `AzureUtils` - this way you can at least shield your own code from the effects from the design decisions by Microsoft
- you enable the new experimental feature within Mockito that allows mocking final classes
- you turn to PowerMock(ito) or JMockit

Comment: The Azure class is final and has a private constructor and is meant to be used only in a static context.  Why Microsoft??? Why?

Comment: @DRaehal Ah, well. A lot of people make the argument that using **final** is a good thing when creating APIs - because you make your intention very clear when using it. I updated my answer accordingly. Let me know if the changes make the answer maybe upvote worthy in your eyes.

Comment: [azure-resourcemanager_2.13.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/releases/tag/azure-resourcemanager_2.13.0) is a `private final` static builder class with a `private` constructor. The only way to get an instance of the class is by going through the `authenticate()` method, e.g. `AzureResourceManager.authenticate().abc().xyz()`. This has been difficult for me to test. My internet searches led me here.

Comment: Dammit. Missed the 5 min edit window. `final` not `private final`

Comment: Glad you found my 8 year old content helpful ;-)